How to combine several semi-transparent images so that one covers another in GIMP?
I have several semi-transparent images which i want to place one over another.
But by default GIMP blends them, so the transparency of both images mixes. I only want so that the "upper" layer would be visible (basically in the overlapping part of the layer should just be this semitransparent color of the "highest" layer and that's it).
I tried different blending modes, but they all seem to not work with alpha channel as i want.
Is there easy way to do it without making masks?

Masks is the way to go if you want varying transparency over the image surface.
A mask is basically a black-grey-white image where black represents 'full transparency' and white 'opaque'.
When applied to a "layer" that layer will be transparent for black positions in the mask, showing any layer behind (under) it.
Create a mask? Right click a layer, and you'll have it in the menu which shows up.
More:
https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Layer_Masks/
Compare to:
https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-concepts-layer-modes.html
